# Blocking fallback form when javascript is enabled

Tags: html, javascript, css

I'm trying to setup a page where people can submit data in a form, but the presentation of the form is based on whether the user has javascript and/or CSS enabled or not.

Currently I have a code similar to the following code to achieve my requirements:

```
<a href="/non-javascript-form" onclick="javascriptform()">Fill in data</a>
<div ID="javascriptform">
    <form action="submit.php" method="post">
        Enter data: <input type="text" name="data">
        <input type="submit" value="send data">
    </form>
</div>
<script>
function javascriptform(){
    document.getElementById("javascriptform").display="block";
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Then on the /non-javascript-form page I have centents similar to this:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    Enter data: <input type="text" name="data">
    <input type="submit" value="send data">
</form>
```

and in CSS, I would have:

```
#javascriptform{display:none}
```

I'm trying to avoid forcing those without javascript to load a second page to access the form when the form is already in the code on the first page.

My idea works if both CSS and Javascript are disabled, then I could change the href value to a hash while people could see the form. Also, it works if CSS and Javascript are both enabled.

But what about the case **where CSS is enabled and javascript is disabled**?

If I were to avoid the link going to the separate page, the people in this situation will have no way of seeing the form unless they turn CSS off.

The only other way I could pull this off which could wreck CEO guidelines is to make a script that causes the form to disappear *AFTER* its loaded, thereby causing a bit of flicker.

Is there a way I can make a piece of javascript code that causes an element to be hidden before it has the chance to appear on screen and without requiring visitors to upgrade their browsers?

Comment: This was solved before CSS was invented. Use the `noscript` tag

Comment: See here: [`<noscript>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)